# List with percentage

Tags: php, mysql, join, percentage

I'm trying to make percentage of test answers.

I have mysql db with 3 tables

table `tests`

```
id | name
---+--------
1  | test 1
2  | test 2
```

Table `questions` with tests' questions

```
id | name       | test_id
---+------------+--------
1  | question 1 | 1
2  | question 2 | 1
3  | question 3 | 1
4  | question 4 | 1
5  | question 1 | 2
6  | question 2 | 2
7  | question 3 | 2
8  | question 4 | 2
```

Table `answers` where I put all the answers from tests

```
id | question_id
---+-------------
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 5
4  | 6
5  | 7
6  | 8
```

How can I get a list with percents of done questions within a test. In this case like this:

```
name   | percentage
-------+-----------
test 1 | 50
test 2 | 100
```

Comment: where do you get the percentage?

Comment: I am supposed to calculate them - 100 * count(answers from specific test) / count(all answers from specific test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
select t.name, 
       cast((count(a.id) / count(q.id)) * 100 as unsigned) as percentage
from tests t
left outer  join questions q on q.test_id = t.id
left outer  join answers a on a.question_id = q.id
group by t.name
```

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73f04/25) example

Comment: I updated again. If you like you can use this even shorter query.